# Click div and show its value on another div (javascript_

Tags: javascript

I am building a javascript calculator and I'm stuck on displaying clicked keys to the display div.

HTML:

```
<div class="obudowa">
  <div class="inside-body">
    <span class="title">
    Electronic Calculator
  </span>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="display">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="key ac">AC</div>
    <div class="key CE">CE</div>
    <div class="key divide">&divide</div>
    <div class="key multiply">&times</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="key number seven">7</div>
    <div class="key number eight">8</div>
    <div class="key number nine">9</div>
    <div class="key minus">-</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="key number four">4</div>
    <div class="key number five">5</div>
    <div class="key number six">6</div>
    <div class="key plus">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="key number one">1</div>
    <div class="key number two">2</div>
    <div class="key number three">3</div>
    <div class="key equal">=</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="key number zero">0</div>
    <div class="key dot">.</div>
  </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var calculator = {
  displayer: document.querySelector(".display"),
  numbers: document.querySelectorAll(".number"),
  keys: document.querySelectorAll(".key"),
  inputting: function(){
    for (var key in this.keys) {
      key.addEventListener("click", function(){
       this.displayer.innerHTML += key.innerHTML; 
      })
    }
  },
}
```

So I want to click on calculator.keys and add its value to calcuator.displayer by using calculator.inputting method. I'd like it done only using pure javascript.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/akyjoon/pen/zEgQKr

Comment: You never run the function `calculator.inputting()` in the first place, so the key listeners are not applied. but with that for loop it might not work with your element array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your existing code, change `inputting` code to the following:

```
inputting: function(){
  var displayer = this.displayer;
  for (i=0;i<this.keys.length;i++)
  {
    var key = this.keys[i];   
    key.addEventListener("click", function(){
      displayer.innerHTML += this.innerHTML; 
    })
  }
},
```

Also, don't forget to call `calculator.inputting();` in DOM ready.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the answer I'm looking for. Why do we need to inclue "var displayer = this.displayer", when we already have "displayer: document.querySelector(".display")"?

Comment: Because the scope of `this` changes inside the function of event listener and that's the reason I store it in local variable.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
 var displayer= document.querySelector(".display");
  var numbers= document.querySelectorAll(".number");
  var keys= document.querySelectorAll(".key");
keys.forEach(key=>{
    key.addEventListener("click", function(){
       displayer.innerHTML += key.innerHTML; 
      })
});
```

[Working fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzmWvy)

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions are possible here:

- use closure to keep actual element, as suggested by @jitender
- use [function bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind current element to function
- use [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) which will point to actual element
- ...

Please read about [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to better understand your original problem

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution that you can use if you really want to make use of the calculator object. I suggest you also to pay attention when using "this" because most of the times is not holding what you expect.

Here is a good explanation of this.
https://toddmotto.com/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript/

```
var calculator = {
  displayer: document.querySelector(".display"),
  numbers: document.querySelectorAll(".number"),
  keys: document.querySelectorAll(".key")
};

calculator.keys.forEach(key => {
    key.addEventListener("click", function(){
       calculator.displayer.innerHTML += key.innerHTML; 
    });
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PJMvjd